# Allowing an Interface to return a Class in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface

Is there a way for an interface to return voids as well as classes?

Interface

```
public interface IAnimalSlide<C> where <C>:ImageViewer
{
  void endShow();
  imageViewer displayImage();
  void setNewImage();
}
```

CatSlide

```
public class Cat: IAnimalShow
...

public System.Windows.Controls.ImageViewer displayImage(){
     return displaySingeImage();
}
```

ImageSlideShow

```
public class SlideShow 
{
   IAnimalSlide = prevSlide;
   IAnimalSlide = nextSlide;
   List<IAnimalSlide> animalList;
}   

... 
animalList.catList.ToList<IAnimalSlide>(); //where catList is a list of Cats
Canvas.showImage(IAnimalSlide.displayImage());
```

I'm currently getting an error that says

Using a generic type 'IAnimalSlide' requires 1 type of arguments

The ImageSlideShow calls a class called ImageViewer and I want to call that in the interface. Is there a way I can incorporate that class within the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using a generic type 'IAnimalSlide' requires 1 type of arguments

The error is because your generic `IAnimalSlide` requires a compile-time type to be declared whenever it is used:

```
IAnimalSlide<ImageViewer> slide;
```

But it is unclear what you are asking exactly. You can "allow an interface to return a type" by returning the type from the interface:

```
public interface IAnimalSlide
{
    void EndShow();
    ImageViewer DisplayImage(); // <-- Note the casing of the return type
    void SetNewImage();
}
```

There is no constraint that the interface must be generic (if that is what you are asking).

> **NOTE:** I purposely made the method names Pascal case because that is the standard practice in c# (this ain't Java, dude). See [Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions).

Comment: Thank you for the note at the end there.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few things going on here.  First, your generic interface does not utilize the generic type argument `C`.  If you will use different classes derived from `ImageViewer`, you would use the following:

```
public interface IAnimalSlide<TImageViewer>
    where TImageViewer : ImageViewer
{
    void endShow();
    void setNewImage();
    TImageViewer displayImage();
}
```

Note that the type used for `ImageViewer` in the interface is the generic type argument (which I renamed to make it more descriptive).  Then, when referenced, you would include a type derived from (or is) `ImageViewer`:

```
IAnimalSlide<ImageViewer>
```

However, it seems that you just want to use an `ImageViewer` and won't be using classes derived from it, in which case you do not need a generic interface; simply remove the generic type arugment and specify the `ImageViewer` return type for the `displayImage` method:

```
public interface IAnimalSlide
{
    void endShow();
    void setNewImage();
    ImageViewer displayImage();
}
```

You'll run into other problems based on the remainder of your code, but this should get you past the error in your question.